# Why custom validation in Laravel 5.6 isn't working?

Tags: php, laravel

I created a custom rule with php artisan make:rule, set it in controller, but it not working. What the problem can be?

```php
class CheckDeliveryDate implements Rule
{
    public $client_id;
    private $is_after_midday;
    private $error_messge;

    public function __construct(int $client_id)
    {
        $this->client_id = $client_id;
        $this->is_after_midday = Carbon::now()->greaterThan(Carbon::now()->midDay());
        $this->error_messge = 'Error';
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $delivery_date = Carbon::parse($value);

        if ($delivery_date->isToday()) {
            $this->error_messge = 'Error';

            return false;
        }
        if ($delivery_date->endOfDay()->isPast()) {
            $this->error_messge = 'Error';

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return $this->error_messge;
    }
}
```

In controller i set method rules:

```php
public function rules($client_id)
{
    return [
        'orders.*.positions.*.delivery_time' => [
            'required',
            'date',
            new CheckDeliveryDate($client_id)
        ],
    ];
}
```

and when i store my order, validator->fails() return me "false".

```php
$validator = Validator::make(
    $request->all(),
    $this->rules($client_id)
);
```

I tried set dd or dump in Rule, not working. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Are you sure about this `'orders.*.positions.*.delivery_time'`?

Comment: yeah, shure. Another validations is work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong JSON format date. This is amazing mistake...

Answer (score 0):

As stated on laravel documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules) you are not supposed to pass the parameter to your custom rule instance. Laravel does it for you.

Thus:

```
new CheckDeliveryDate($client_id)
```

Becomes :

```
new CheckDeliveryDate
```

Have a nice day !

Comment: It another parameter and i removed it, but it stil not work